# Can I pass socket from managed c# code to WinRT component?

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

According to my requirement I am creating a socket in C# code and I have to write data on it.
Can I pass that socket to WinRT component and do the write operation there??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.

However, you could create a WinRT socket in your native component (C++), and expose write-operations, that you can access from your managed (C#) component. We do something similar with Skype for Windows Phone.

But it all depends on exactly what you are trying to achieve.